# Extending Activerecord through JSON Api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, activerecord, extend

I am trying to do an App for mobiles, and want to use Rails as my backend. I like very much Activerecord and I want to offer the most used method of his query interface through the JSON API (find, first, last, and so on). I think there sould be a gem to do this, but not find it.

With the standar rails scaffolding i only can query for a specific record like:

```
http://myhost:3000/mycontroller/index/1.json
```

I also want to know, if there is any syntax available for the request, to specify any kind of filters, like "id between 1 and 10", or "created_Date>=01-01-2013", etc...

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [has_scope](https://github.com/plataformatec/has_scope) gem. It does not expose the ActiveRecord finder methods to your API (which is rather unsafe), but it provides some fantastic helpers for exposing AR scopes to it.

Comment: not exactly wath I'am looking for, but can be a good approach if no gem is found for the issue. Thanks

Comment: What I've done in the past is right my index action like this: `@foo= Foo.where(params[:q])` and then whatever is passed into the q param is  passed as an AR query option... This is really quite dangerous, though.... I do not recommend doing what you are asking for.

Comment: Yes, I think it is dangerous too. Exposing the `where` method can inccur in a Sql Injection attack. But I don't want to expose all methods, only a subset of them. I know I can make an action for each method I want to expose, but I am looking for a gem that helps with this issue, so that do not repeat myself :) Thanks for the contribution @cpuguy83